# How to sort processes by time started?

Tags: windows, windows-8, task-manager

In task manager (or using alternative software if not an option), how do you sort processes by time started? If for example, you were concerned that you may have installed a virus, you might want to view the most recent few processes and inspect them.

(I do not know if the time started is a stored property of processes, if not then this obviously would not be possible.)

Answer (score 4):

You can install a program called [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to view all running processes along with their start times.

1. Open **Process Explorer**
2. Click the **View** menu and then click **Select Columns…**
3. In the **Process Performance** tab, mark the checkbox next to **Start Time**, and click **OK**.

This will show you an additional column named **Start Time** for each process listed.

--**Another Option**--

If you don't want to install a new program, you can query Windows Management Instrumentation for this instead.

1. Open the Command Prompt window by clicking the **Start** button, clicking **All Programs**, clicking **Accessories**, and then clicking **Command Prompt**.
2. Enter the following command: `wmic process get name,creationdate` and then press **Enter**

You will see output like this with the creation date+time listed, followed by the name of the process, sorted by the time the process was started:

```
20150121161522.832200-480  cmd.exe
20150121161522.962200-480  conhost.exe
20150121162132.567200-480  WMIC.exe
20150121162132.622200-480  WmiPrvSE.exe
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PowerShell`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847889.aspx) and the `Get-Process` commandlet like so:

`Get-Process | select name, starttime`

This will display all processes running and the time they started.

Comment: In case it helps someone else, can pipe this to the clipboard: `Get-Process | select name, starttime | clip`. If using Google Sheets, `Data > Split text to columns` after pasting takes it from there.

Comment: How to sort the output by starttime? By default, it is sorted by name. The `wmic` command on the other hand sorts by creationdate by default.