# Is it possible to know/sort processes by "activation time" in Task Manager?

Tags: windows-10, window, task-manager

I'm using windows 10 .

Is it possible to know from task manager / SORT the task manager's list according to : "time elapsed since running" ?

cpu/cpu time doesn't seems to do it.

For example , Currently `calc.exe` is not running.

Now I run it :

[image]

But I can't find a column which  , when I sort by it - I will be able to know `calc.exe`'s running time.

**Question :**

How can I know/sort processes and their activation time?

Additional info : Here are the columns :

[image]

** Another solutions ( without using task manager ) are also welcomed (but please , no utilities download).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can sort processes by activation time. But for this you have to use [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Another way is by using the **Command Prompt**

Open cmd and run these:
**wmic process get name,creationdate**

Please follow this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/867822/how-to-sort-processes-by-time-started).

Thank you.

Comment: "but please , no utilities download" ...

Comment: The OP asked "Is it possible using Task Manager...". Since the answer states "...you have to use Process Explorer.", surely the first word in the answer should be "No"?